# Find input button within a selected class div

Tags: jquery, button, jquery-ui-accordion

How could I use jquery to find out this button within a div with class name "blueheaderbar accordionButton on" then change button value to "hide it"

```
<div class="blueheaderbar accordionButton selected" style="margin-top:20px">
            <div class="floatleft">abc</div>
            <div class="floatright"><input class="showhidebtn" type="button" value="Show Outlet" style="margin:6px 16px 0 0; width:86px" /></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="blueheaderbar accordionButton" style="margin-top:20px">
            <div class="floatleft">abc</div>
            <div class="floatright"><input class="showhidebtn" type="button" value="Show Outlet" style="margin:6px 16px 0 0; width:86px" /></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the answer is:

```
$("div.blueheaderbar.selected").find("input").val("hide it");
```

Answer (score 2):

`"blueheaderbar accordionButton selected"` isn't "a" single class name, but three. The CSS selector to select an element with all three classes is

```
.blueheaderbar.accordionButton.selected
```

(notice the lack of spaces!).

So to find an input inside there with jQuery is:

```
var $input = jQuery(".blueheaderbar.accordionButton.selected input");
```

or

```
var $input = jQuery(".blueheaderbar.accordionButton.selected").find("input");
```

Answer (score 2):

this will do the trick-

```
jQuery(".blueheaderbar.accordionButton.selected").find(".showhidebtn").hide();
```

and for secon div try this-

```
jQuery(".blueheaderbar.accordionButton").find(".showhidebtn").hide();
```

you can try in this way also-

```
jQuery(".blueheaderbar.accordionButton.selected > .showhidebtn").hide();
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AkRqe/)

Answer (score 1):

This should change the text

```
$('.showhidebtn').click(function() {
  $(this).val('hide it');
});
```